# Is the cylindrical transform an open mapping

Tags: general-topology

Consider the cylindrical transformation:
$$f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3, f(r,\theta,z)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,z),$$

Is $f$ an open mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the notation confusing: to me, "$f(r,\theta,z)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,z)$" looks like an identity map because I imagine $r,\theta,z$ being cylindrical coordinates. Let's write $x,y,z$ for the coordinates in the domain. Then $f(x,y,z)=(u,v,w)$ where 
$$u=x\cos y, \ v=x\sin y, \ w=z$$ 
This is not an open map. Specifically, the image of the ball $B$ with center $(0,0,0)$ and radius $1$ contains $f(0,0,0)=(0,0,0)$ but does not contain any points of the form $(0,\epsilon,0)$. Spoiler ahead.

> Note that $\cos y$ does not vanish in $B$. This implies that $v=0$ whenever $u=0$.